# How to properly communicate between docker containers on an existing network?

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, docker-network

I have the following `docker-compose.yml` config:

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  client:
    container_name: client
    image: client
    build: 
      context: .
    networks:
      - test_net
    volumes:
      - ./:/client/code
  timescaledb:
    container_name: timescaledb
    image: 'timescale/timescaledb-ha:pg14-latest'
    networks:
      - test_net
    ports:
      - '9999:5432'
    volumes:
      - timescaledb:/home/postgres/pgdata/data
      - ./scripts/:/home/postgres/scripts/
      - ./scripts/init/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

volumes:
  timescaledb:
networks:
  test_net:
    name: test_net
    external: true
```

"test_net" is a custom network that I created via `docker network create test_net` and I am trying to get the client container (from the python:3.10.0-slim-buster image) to properly establish a connection with a postgresql database container on this network. I have run `docker inspect timescaledb` and have found its IPAddress to be 172.20.0.3

When I run the following steps:

1. `docker compose up timescaledb`
2. `docker compose up client`

the client attempts to connect to the database with sqlalchemy's `create_engine` using the dbstring "postgresql://user:password@172.20.0.3:9999", however this always times out with the following:

```
client  | sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not connect to server: Connection timed out
client  |        Is the server running on host "172.20.0.3" and accepting
client  |        TCP/IP connections on port 9999?
client  | 
client  | (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not connect to server: Connection timed out
        Is the server running on host "172.20.0.3" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 9999?

(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)
```

I must be doing something incorrectly with the network configuration or port mapping, but I can't seem to figure it out..

Any guidance would be appreciated!

**Update:**

I attempted to ping the db container and this also timed out, so it looks like the problem might be network related?

```
$ docker exec -it client ping timescaledb
PING timescaledb (172.20.0.3) 56(84) bytes of data.

^C
--- timescaledb ping statistics ---
80 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 967ms
```

```
$ docker network inspect test_net
[
    {
        "Name": "test_net",
        "Id": "0df6af7ab0718df178aafa083ee131f741d73ae553b9022b2db6b8c7fb441569",
        "Created": "2023-01-16T14:09:03.721731326-05:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": {},
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.20.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.20.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "6b692ef3a1bdfe6a7aec34f17fcc4ad7d9b829bc0664c3be745cd80ccf8b1acc": {
                "Name": "client",
                "EndpointID": "7e4736c818686be4616b3f262f329dfd51acb34c125a3f217ce39078b51604a4",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "a3eb16c81ea134ffdbcd1ead2801e7995ee95e063220bf5eccb5469633399bac": {
                "Name": "timescaledb",
                "EndpointID": "1938fdf71a59def5c0732a17219eedfef9dac7299699688bced6065480ac5142",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

Comment: Where does the magic IP address come from?  Can you use the Compose service name of the database `timescaledb` with the standard PostgreSQL port 5432?  (Connections between services don't use or require `ports:`.)

Comment: The IP comes from inspecting the docker network for the "timescaledb" host. I tried your suggestion and the same OperationalError comes up, but it at least infers the same/correct IP!

Comment: You're trying to connect to port 9999, but postgres is listening port 5432. Port publishing impacts the port on which the service is exposed **on your host**, but has no impact on container-to-container communication.

Comment: I see.. unfortunately I removed the port mapping and attempted to connect instead on port 5432 and the same connection timeout still occurs.

Comment: Edited the original post with an update. It looks like there might be an issue elsewhere.

Comment: `ping` is generally a poor diagnostic tool (because success or failure of `ping` doesn't necessarily translate to success or failure for a particular application). Is the `timescaledb` container running? Are there any errors in the logs? It looks to me like you're failing to set some required environment variables (like `POSTGRES_PASSWORD`). See [the docs](https://docs.timescale.com/install/latest/installation-docker/) for details.

Comment: Yep, the container is up. The env var isn't necessary in this case because the database already exists.

However, I did look into the `timescaledb` logs and I noticed that it says `listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432`. Should there be a mention of the docker subnet instead maybe?

Comment: No, that's entirely normal (`0.0.0.0` means "all addresses").